# unable to read data from object array in php

Tags: php, object

```
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2020-05-10 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => UTC )
```

above show when I do `print_r` 
below is the code

```
$bb=$row['dueDate'];

print_r($bb);
echo $bb->date;
```

now problem when i remove print_r command  then `$bb->date` not show where as when `print_r($bb)` then it show echo data of `$bb->date` how to fixed this

Comment: Please work over your question. I can not even guess what you want to achive.

Answer (score 1):

In general terms you don't *echo* objects.

For the [DateTime](https://php.net/DateTime) class you possibly want to call the [format()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method. E.g.:

```
echo $bb->format('r');
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow @Álvaro González Answer.

You cannot echo directly from the date-time object.
Try to use-

```
<?php
$bb = $row['dueDate']; //date-time object

echo date_format($bb, 'h:i:sa d M Y');  //use date_format($date_time_object, $date_format)
```